# Java Statement.executeUpdate to delete all rows fails in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, prepared-statement

I am running a very simple query against Oracle DB to delete all rows from a table:

```
delete my_table_name
```

This works fine when running in SQL developer.

But when I use `Statement` to delete them, they don't get deleted (yes, table has rows in it).

Following is the code:

```
try (Statement deleteDups = connection.createStatement()) {
    deleteDups.executeUpdate("delete my_table_name");
    connection.commit();
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem? The docs say PreparedStatment#executeUpdate returns _either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing_

Comment: I am getting funny feeling about your `sql`, should't it be `delete from some_table`?

Comment: @jlars62. I fixed the problem description.

Comment: @Smit I already tried the query you said, that does not work either.

Comment: @Prasanna and you are sure you are able to compile your code? As I dont think the snippet you have provided will let you compile?

Comment: @Smit. With Java 7, yes, this will compile.

Comment: @Prasanna +1, You are correct. But where is your prepared statement? And is your `Connection object is in auto-commit mode`. I think if you `connection.commit();` remove this statement. your java code will work.

Comment: @Prasanna Did you solved your problem?